# dll injection - simple main

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I'm tring to inject a dll to an .exe, i code this simple main but my file isn't created.
I inject it with a cpp code, but i don't think the injector is the problem.

```
DWORD WINAPI Main_thread( LPVOID lpParam)
{
  std::ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("C:\\Users\\root\\Desktop\\example.txt");
  myfile << "success" << std::endl;
  myfile.close();
  return S_OK;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  _reason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
  if (_reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
     CreateThread(0, 0x1000, &Main_thread, 0, 0, NULL);
  return true;
}
```

the injector code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

using namespace std;
bool InjectDLL(DWORD ProcessID);

char dllPath[250] = "C:\\Users\\root\\Desktop\\testdll\\bin\\Debug\\testdll.dll";
char ProcessName[] = "chrome.exe";
typedef HINSTANCE (*fpLoadLibrary)(char*);

int main()
{
DWORD processId = NULL;
PROCESSENTRY32 pe32 = {sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32)};
HANDLE hProcSnap;
hProcSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
if(Process32First(hProcSnap, &pe32))
{
    do{
         if(!strcmp(pe32.szExeFile, ProcessName))
        {
            processId = pe32.th32ProcessID;
            break;
        }
    }while(Process32Next(hProcSnap, &pe32));
}
if (!InjectDLL(processId))
        cout << "DLL failed to inject" << endl;
}

bool InjectDLL(DWORD ProcessID)
{
HANDLE hProc;
LPVOID paramAddr;
HINSTANCE hDll = LoadLibrary("KERNEL32");
fpLoadLibrary LoadLibraryAddr = (fpLoadLibrary)GetProcAddress(hDll, "LoadLibraryA");
hProc = OpenProcess (PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, ProcessID);
paramAddr = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, 0, strlen(dllPath)+1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
bool memoryWritten = WriteProcessMemory(hProc, paramAddr, dllPath, strlen(dllPath)+1, NULL);
CreateRemoteThread(hProc, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryAddr, paramAddr, 0, 0);
CloseHandle(hProc);
return memoryWritten;
}
```

the dll don't seem to be injected or he could'nt write,
I didn't launch the injector as root

Comment: Why don't you think the injector is the problem? Have you verified that the DLL is loaded into the target process?

Comment: because i used one I made and one I found on the internet, but its still possible.

Comment: You should show us the injector and give us more details: does the injector return success? Does the process you are trying to inject run under the same account as the injector? Are you an administrator or power user on the machine? Etc.

Comment: my way to do X does not achieve X. I am therefore pretty sure that my way to do X is not the problem.

Comment: I post my injector code

Comment: Does `InjectDLL` succeed? It calls a number of functions that are likely to return a failure without checking their result (e.g. `OpenProcess` requesting `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` and `CreateRemoteThread`.) Add error checking to those functions and make sure that `InjectDLL` returns success, and if it does and you still have issues, then we can revisit this. As it stands now, I suspect the issue is with `InjectDLL`.

Comment: Creating a thread in DllMain is very dangerous and likely to either, fail, deadlock or crash

Comment: @paulm: very right - you're not supposed to use API calls in general, especially ones that may cause other DLLs to be loaded. Raymond Chen has written extensively only this. This is one such blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/27/63401.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can diagnose your problem from Task Manager, add the PID column.  Or use SysInternals' Process Explorer.  You'll see that Chrome.exe starts up many instances of itself.  The primary one just display the UI and is not involved in browsing web pages.  You'll see the other ones, one each for each tab you have opened in the browser.

Those other instances are special, they run the add-ons and scripting code in a *sandbox*.  Designed to make Chrome resilient to web pages or script that can crash or hang the browser.  But especially to run code in a runtime environment that removes all privileges so it cannot mess with the user's machine.  Like the kind of code that you are trying to write.

So your Process32First/Next() iterator is way too simple, it will pick off whatever instance of Chrome.exe it finds first.  With a high likelihood that it is a sandboxed one, the kind that won't let you mess with it.  You could only inject the instance that the user started, the one that only displays the UI.  Which is usually where the usefulness of this kind of hacking ends, there just isn't anything interesting to mess with in that instance.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that he was trying to inject into `chrome.exe`. It's quite possible, as you write, that the failure is caused by the aggressive measures that Chrome takes to sandbox and isolate things. Good catch.